# Type mismatch for <apex:attribute assignTo>. Value binding to a property of type ANY is required, property specified (objectValue) is of type Object

Tags: visualforce-component, winter15, spring15

I need a bit of guidance here.

I'm working with a visual force which actually was correctly deployed in an org (and working fine), through an ant target, using salesforce tool.

Note that not all components are using associated controllers, once I tried to save my Visual Force without any change, suddenly appears following error compile message:

**Type mismatch for . Value binding to a property of type ANY is required, property specified (objectValue) is of type Object.**

I've replicated error in Spring 15 and Winter 15 Salesforce version and result is the same in both of them.

I'm using API v24 in Visual Forces.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

KR, Javi

Comment: Have you tried different API Versions? If you don't have a controller, `assignTo` should not work...

Comment: Thanks for took time to reply. We have in our project a custom component and each of attributes in the component have each assingTo related with a controller. Problem was that for some reason ToolingAPI is causing the issue, we've changed our mavensmate configuration in order to use MDApi and now compiles correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen something similar with object params in custom components. It may be a failure in the tooling API.

If you're using Mavensmate then try switching from Tooling API to MDAPI in your config.

In a browser, if it fails in Dev Console, try performing the edit in the setup menu: develop

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this result to be a known issue by salesforce and seems to be fixed. Please check following link for more info.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XvGAAU

Comment: This issue is not fixed. The work around works. But the problem is, you will still not be able to edit the file via the Developer Console: the same error keeps coming up when trying to save. Any idea when this will be fixed in the Developer Console?